# PyQt - QLabel inheriting

Tags: python, qt, inheritance, pyqt, label

i wanna inherit QLabel to add there click event processing.
I'm trying this code:

```
class NewLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def clickEvent(self, event):
        print 'Label clicked!'
```

But after clicking I have no line 'Label clicked!'

**EDIT:**

Okay, now I'm using not 'clickEvent' but 'mousePressEvent'. And I still have a question. How can i know what exactly label was clicked? For example, i have 2 edit box and 2 labels. Labels content are pixmaps. So there aren't any text in labels, so i can't discern difference between labels. How can i do that?

**EDIT2:**
I made this code:

```
class NewLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, firstLabel):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, firstLabel)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print 'Clicked'
        #myLabel = self.sender()  # None =)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), "Label pressed")
```

In another class:

```
self.FirstLang = NewLabel(Form)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.FirstLang, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.labelPressed)
```

Slot in the same class:

```
def labelPressed(self):
    print 'in labelPressed'
    print self.sender()
```

But there isn't sender object in self. What i did wrong?

Comment: I don't know how PyQt works but you get sender() from QObject, did the class with the labelPressed slot inherit from QObject? it should since it has a slot... atleast in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your second question, I'll continue based on @gnud example:

- subclass QLabel, override mouseReleaseEvent and add a signal to the class, let's call it clicked.
- check which button was clicked in mouseReleaseEvent, if it's the left one emit the clicked signal.
- connect a slot to your labels clicked signal and use [sender()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qobject.html#sender) inside to know which QLabel was clicked.

Answer (score 3):

There is no function `clickEvent` in QWidget/QLabel. You could connect that function to a Qt signal, or you could do:

```
class NewLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setText('Lorem Ipsum')

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print 'Label clicked!'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the [PyQt Wiki](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Making%20non-clickable%20widgets%20clickable) works very well but I would add that the `clickable` class should call `widget.mouseReleaseEvent` (right before `return True`), just in case the user has customized this event.

Comment: Good point - but it would be even more correct for the `eventFilter` to simply `return False` in all cases (since it is not actually handling the event).